# Есть способы сделать цветной шрифт в терминале?

Tags: java, linux, шрифты, библиотеки, терминал

Используя сторонние библиотеки, или нативные библиотеки Java, можно сделать цветной шрифт в терминале? Может что-то наподобие printf? 
И есть возможность сделать индикатор загрузки используя слеши, как в том же Linux?(\ | / -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывести символьный индикатор процесса легко

```
char[] sym = { '\\', '|', '/', '-' };
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    System.out.print(sym[x % 4] + "\r");
    Thread.sleep(200);
}
```

С цветами сложнее. Чтобы сохранить кроссплатформенность понадобиться библиотека [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi):

```
System.out.println(ansi().eraseScreen()
                         .fg(RED)
                         .a("Hello")
                         .fg(GREEN)
                         .a(" World")
                         .reset());
```

Comment: Первый способ почему то не работает. Либо ничего не выводится, либо выводится слеш и через некоторое время дефис.

Comment: Странно, проверил и в консоли Windows и в консоли Debian, работает.

Comment: Так я использую IDEA, может там что-то с терминалом? Сейчас попробую через консоль.

Comment: Конечно, IDE выполняет программу, получает её вывод и только потом выводит его в свою консоль. Более того, в ней и Jansi работать скорее всего не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Посмотрите это [Управляющие последовательности ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI). Но надо понимать, что ANSI последовательности для разных терминалов могут различаться.

Для реализации прогресс бара на Java в терминальном режиме существует большое количество библиотек. Их легко найти с помощью любой поисковой системы, например:https://github.com/ctongfei/progressbar или https://github.com/raszi/java-progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать enum Class:

```
public enum TextColor {
    RESET("\u001B[0m"),
    BLACK("\u001B[30m"),
    RED("\u001B[31m"),
    GREEN("\u001B[32m"),
    YELLOW("\u001B[33m"),
    BLUE("\u001B[34m"),
    PURPLE("\u001B[35m"),
    CYAN("\u001B[36m"),
    GREY("\u001B[37m");
    private String ansiCode;
    private TextColor(String ansiCode){
        this.ansiCode = ansiCode;
    }

    public void setAnsi_code(java.lang.String ansiCode) {
        this.ansiCode = ansiCode;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.ansiCode;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
    import static text.colors.TextColor;
    //...
    System.out.println(RED);
    System.out.println("This text has red color");
    System.out.println(BLACK);
    System.out.println("This text has black color");
    System.out.println(RESET);
    System.out.println("This text has normal color");
```